# How do I get rid of the message: "Inverse functions are being used by Solve, ...; use Reduce for complete solution information."

Tags: warning-messages

OK.  I get it.  I understand the difference.  How do I permanently suppress this message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I permanently suppress this message?

use `Off[Solve::ifun]`

[image]

Then the message will not show again. To turn it back on, do `On[Solve::ifun]`